# External CSS file won't work with one page in particular

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I'm a beginner and I'm creating my first website, but I've stumbled with one page that will not recognize the CSS it's linked to.

I've linked each html page of the website to its own CSS style sheet and they all work, except for one. All the files are in the same root folder and if I check the 'Page Source' when opening my problematic page in a browser (FireFox) there are no errors showing up, so I'm really lost.

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
 font-family: Tahoma;
}

nav { 
 display: inline-block;
 float: right;
 font-family: Tahoma;
}

address {
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>About X</title>
<LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="about.css">
</head>



<body>
<header>
<img src="images\logo.jpg" width="100" height="80" alt="logo">
<h1>Mister X</h1>
<nav> 
<a href=///C:/Users/Soniaa/Desktop/web%20design/webpage.html>Pictures</a>
<a href=file:///C:/Users/Soniaa/Desktop/web%20design/News.html>News</a>
<a href=file:///C:/Users/Soniaa/Desktop/web%20design/About.html>About</a>
<a href="http://www.saatchiart.com/sorinatibacov">Shop</a>
</nav>email@gmail.com</address>
</header>

<figure><img src="images/pic.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="Portrait"> 
<figcaption>Short Bio... </figcaption>
</figure>

<h2>Education</h2>
 
<ul>
<li>this</li>
<li>that</li>
</ul>


<h2>Personal Exhibitions</h2>

<dl>
<dt>2010</dt>
<dd>...</dd>
  
<dt>2006</dt>
<dd>...<dd>

<dd>...</dd>



<h2>Group Exhibitions</h2>

<dl>
<dt>2008</dt>
<dd>...</dd>
<dd>...</dd>



<footer>© Mister x <br> 

<A HREF="https://www.facebook.com/..."><IMG SRC="images/fb.png" width="30" height="30" ALT="Facebook"></A>
<A HREF="https://www.behance.net/...><IMG SRC="images/be.png" width="30" height="30" ALT="Behance"></A> <br>

Webdesign by me </footer>




</body>
</html>
```

The actual page has a lot of definition lists in it (no idea if that would have anything to do with it).

The same CSS works with my "Home" page, for example, which has the same header.

Maybe I'm missing something very obvious, but any help would appreciated!

EDIT: Thank you to everyone who took the time to answer!
Unfortunately I didn't find the problem but I think maybe I didn't give enough details so I'll rephrase and repost the question (I didn't want to delete this because someone else might find a helpful answer for themselves).

Hope that's okay...

Comment: When you use your console (usually right clicking and selecting 'inspect element' is the easiest way to get there - the inspector panel should contain a console), does it report a `file not found` error? Also, there seems to be a couple of unbalanced tags (like `</address>` in your `nav` - it was never opened)

Comment: could you please post the html in which css works and html file where csss do not works ?

Comment: _“I've linked each html page of the website to its own CSS style sheet”_ – why? Do the formattings of those pages have _nothing_ in common? You should rather put that in into one stylesheet, so that the browser can already fetch it from cache in on the next page. Having a single style sheet for each individual page would make sense only in extreme edge cases; for most normal sites it does not.

Comment: @somethinghere I opened the console, there is nothing at all showing up. Sorry, I think I deleted <address> when posting the question, but it's there in the full html.

Comment: Can you find the css file in the `resources` loaded ?(its probably another panel in your console which will list all of the images and files that were fetched, Chrome shows you a file structure as well).

Comment: @CBroe Oooh, so the pages ARE supposed to share the same CSS file? Sorry, very much a rookie here... But I did try linking the "about" page to the same CSS file the "Home" page has and ... nothing...

Comment: It does not really make a difference - you are just duplicating work. Disregarding best practise here, your issue won't be solved by sharing CSS style sheets :) But yes, you can link all to the same CSS styl;e sheet so you can modify your entire site in one go!

Comment: @somethinghere I can't find "resources" anywhere after clicking "inspect element".

Comment: In Firefox, have a look in the `network` tab, and see if you can find your CSS file listed there with a status of `200`, if so your file is loaded, otherwise you file might be wrongly linked.

Comment: Just delete this; there is nothing here that is/will be helpful for anyone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Is your CSS in the same directory as your HTML file? If it's not you probably should do something like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/about.css">
```

Also make sure you did not make any typo's. If what you are describing is really true it should work.

Comment: I asked this in the comments and am waiting for a reply to the question, if you cannot post comments yet please build up your reputation but do not post comments as answers.

Comment: I am trying to build it up yes, I would've posted as a comment if I could, sorry.

Comment: I know its an annoying restriction, but it's a safety net. I will not downvote you for this, but plenty of people would do which will make it harder to build up reputation.

Comment: Give him an upvote. The rule of don't put comments if you haven't enough reputation is crap.

Comment: @MarcosPerezGude I won't upvote him for what basically amounts to a guess, its not that good an answer (it basically is my comment - and unless this turns out to have answered the question I don't find upvoting useful). The reputation basics makes sense - contribute first, then we can trust your answers. We could debate whether thats good but thats how things are.

Comment: You're right @somethinghere . But I think that disable comments is a really bad idea, because this cases are day by day posted with the guilty rule.

Comment: Rules are rules. If you can't comment yet, it's for a reason. Don't circumvent the system by posting a comment as an answer.

Comment: So I'd just best leave questions like this alone?

Comment: For now, yes, unless you can provide a real answer. Again, there are more people here who would downvote a bad answer (which a comment is) than would upvote you, so don't take the risk for now and focus on getting that 50 reputation and then simply start using the comments. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Your markup is fine there seems to be no problem with it.The files are working perfectly on my computer.Try erasing the history of your browser and then reload it, or change the browser and see if it works.

Comment: The other answer contains some comments on posting comments as answers, which is what this is. Please gain reputation to use the comments, posting comments as answer will not help you reach the 50 reputation you need to post comments.

Comment: Sorry, ill try my best next time. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I am confused, how did this turn out to be marked as correct? I mean, the OP gives absolutely no info on why this would have worked...